# How can i customize message display in kendo grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, angular5, kendo-autocomplete

when searching in kendo autocomplete, the initial text is 'no data found', i want to remove or change to 'searching'. If no records found then it can be show, worst case, i want to set to blank?

I am developing in angular 2 and typescript. i am new to kendo and angular 2 and also typescript. can please help me on that.

### tried code

```
<kendo-autoComplete 
  [data] = "gridData" 
  [valueField]="name" 
  (valueChange)="onValueChange($event, 'family.type')
  (filterChange) = "filterChange($event, 'match.type)
>
  <ng-template kendoAutoCompleTemplete let-dataItem>
    {{dataItem.name}}
  </ng-template>
</kendo-autoComplete>
<input />
```

Comment: Can you add some code you already have ?

Comment: <kendo-autoComplete [data]="gridData" [valueField]="name"

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as suggested in the [Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/templates/#toc-no-data-template) :

```
<kendo-autocomplete [data]="gridData">
    <ng-template kendoAutoCompleteNoDataTemplate>
        <h4><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"></span><br /><br /> No data here</h4>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-autocomplete>
```

You may have to workaround that, but I think it's a good start.

Comment: Can you please help me on that

Comment: What is the result with your try ? And why have you a <input/> in your showed code ?

Comment: When on key up it will call above kend-autocomplete, it working only problem is with message

Comment: I want to change 'no data found' to 'searching'

Comment: Can you add an image of what you have and add your .ts code please.

Comment: On key up it will call the function , in that function , I can display filter data but. How it is coming message I Don't knlow

Comment: The message come from your template. In your code you wrote `kendoAutoCompleTemplete`, try `kendoAutoCompleTemplate ` and maybe use the `kendoAutoCompleteNoDataTemplate` template.

Comment: I wanted to say `kendoAutoCompleteTemplate`

Comment: Here typing mistak